# Firebase DynamicLink Android not received when app coming from background

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm having some issue with Dynamic Links with Android. 
If my app is closed and the link is clicked I can receive the deep link correctly. However, if I send the app to the background and click again the link, this one is not detected by the app anymore.
My code is at the MainActivity and at the same time at the Activity which handles the link.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
              .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
              .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                  @Override
                  public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                      // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
                      Uri deepLink = null;
                      if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                          deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
                          Log.d("DEEP LINK DETECTED", String.valueOf(deepLink));
                          ..
                      }
                  }
              })
              .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                      Log.w(“FAIL DYNAMIC LINK", "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e);
                  }
              });
```

At manifest I've added at both Activities

```
  android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Also, the filters as detailed in documentation

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

   <data
     android:host="xxx.page.link"
     android:scheme="https" />

</intent-filter>
```

Any ideas why my links are not detected the second time when app is opened at the background? 
I'm really stuck here 
Many thanks!

Comment: I am getting same issue , have you resolved this issue or any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because OnCreate is only called when the MainActivity is first created.  When you place the app in the background and then click the link, your app is brought back to the foreground but OnCreate is not fired again.  You should use OnResume instead.